# LinkedIn Assets API: No AWS key returned when registering multi-part upload

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to upload a video > 200MB via https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets. When registering a MULTIPART_UPLOAD I do not receive the "x-amz-server-side-encryption" or "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id" headers information anywhere in the response. I do get those when registering a SINGLE_REQUEST_UPLOAD and I'm able to successfully upload a video file < 200MB using that mechanism.

Example response for registering a multi-part upload:

```
{
  "value": {
    "uploadMechanism": {
      "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MultipartUpload": {
        "metadata": "{METADATA}",
        "partUploadRequests": [
          {
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": "5242880",
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            "urlExpiresAt": 1547231882996,
            "byteRange": {
              "lastByte": 5242879,
              "firstByte": 0
            },
            "url": "{AWS_UPLOAD_URL}"
          },
          {
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": "5242880",
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            "urlExpiresAt": 1547231882996,
            "byteRange": {
              "lastByte": 10485759,
              "firstByte": 5242880
            },
            "url": "{AWS_UPLOAD_URL}"
          },
          {
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": "3585789",
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            "urlExpiresAt": 1547231883023,
            "byteRange": {
              "lastByte": 580302588,
              "firstByte": 576716800
            },
            "url": "{AWS_UPLOAD_URL}"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "mediaArtifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{ASSET_URN},urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:aws-userUploadedVideo)",
    "asset": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{ASSET_URN}"
  }
}
```

I have tried to upload to those urls without the two headers and get a 403 Forbidden response saying I'm missing signed headers. The "x-amz-server-side-encryption" and "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id" should be returned in the register response right? If not, how do I make requests to aws without them?